# How to check yes/no on a table via a form load and reload if that changes

Tags: vba, ms-access

I’m fairly new to ms_access and trying to create a way to check if there is a open record in my database and if so then not allow the form that allows new records entered to be opened.

I am trying to check on form load if any records in a table are checked Yes on a yes/no column.  I need to ensure only one record is editable at a time.

I finally got to halfway work that it will check and either disable or enable the button so they can't input an additional record, however I'm not sure how to continuously recheck it once I close the record out.  It just stays the same once the form loads the first time.  Secondly, I can't get the Caption to change from "start Flight Record to "Flight in Progress" even though the varX comes as -1.

```
Dim varX As Variant 
varX = DLookup("strWorkingRecord", "tblFlightRecords")

If varX = -1 Then Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = False & _
        Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = "Flight In Progress"


If varX <> -1 Then Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = True & _
    Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = "Start Flight Record"
```

Comment: This is a multi-user db and other users might be creating records at same time? How does user start another record once form is opened? Just move to NewRecord row?

Answer (score 0):

All that DLookup does is return value from first record it reads in table - without search criteria the output is random. DLookup returns Null if no match to criteria. Code syntax is not correct - the actions should be on separate lines within `If End If`. Should declare variable to specific type.

```
Dim varX As Boolean 
varX = Nz(DLookup("strWorkingRecord", "tblFlightRecords", "strWorkingRecord=True"), False)
If varX Then 
    Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = False
    Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = "Flight In Progress"
Else 
    Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = True
    Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = "Start Flight Record"
End If
```

Can simplify code.

```
Dim varX As Boolean
varX = Nz(DLookup("strWorkingRecord", "tblFlightRecords", "strWorkingRecord=True"), False)
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = Not varX
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = IIf(varX, "Flight In Progress", "Start Flight Record")
```

Or use DCount().

```
Dim varX As Integer
varX = DCount("*", "tblFlightRecords", "strWorkingRecord=True")
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = Not varX > 0
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = IIf(varX > 0, "Flight In Progress", "Start Flight Record")
```

Comment: `Dim varX As Integer
varX = DCount("*", "tblFlightRecords", "strWorkingRecord=True")
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Enabled = Not varX > 0
Me.cmdOpenEnterRecord.Caption = IIf(varX > 0, "Flight In Progress", "Start Flight Record")`   I ended up using this in two other locations as well with some slight modifications.  Thanks again.